# Does Jesus have a second name?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, name-of-jesus

Somewhat related to [Does Jesus have a last name?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14482/45603).

In Forrest Gump (1994)'s scene where private Gump is assembling his weapon (during a drill exercise in the army) unusually fast, his drill sergeant says (emphasis mine):

> **Jesus H. Christ**! That's a new company record.

Is this a totally fictional saying? Part of script editor vision? Or has it any relation to Jesus actually having second name?

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of the linked question. Could you explain how it is different or maybe [edit] it so it can be different?

Comment: Jesus Emanuel Josephson

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/56408/23657   Most likely a reference to the Greek IHC

Comment: @agarza - I think this is asking whether Jesus has a middle name.  Another question might be whether He received another name like half of His friends. But I don't think there's much evidence for either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back then, people were identified either as being the son of their father, or by the name of the town where they grew up.

In Luke's genealogy, chapter 3 verse 23 identifies Jesus like this:

> Now Jesus himself was about thirty years old when he began his ministry.  He was the son, so it was thought, of Joseph.

Jesus was also identified as Jesus of Nazareth, the son of Joseph (John 1:45).

"Christ" is a title, not a name.  And yes, he was Holy.  He was also known as the Son of God, which demands our reverence.

P.S. Courtesy of User14, from an old CSE question, the letters 'JHS' as used in the Catholic Church mean Jesus Hominum Salvator (Latin: Jesus Savior of Mankind).

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/56408/23657

Comment: Nice one, User 14

Answer (score 1):

The "second name" in its modern form is a European development, late Middle Ages (though the Romans had a more complex system).

The quotation of the middle initial along with the main two names is, as far as I know, a purely American habit.

That should be enough to warn us that the expression "Jesus H Christ" is a modern irreverent joke.

Comment: What about "Jesus Holy Christ" (see above answer)?